# How could I implement the Dipity Timeline UI?

Tags: user-interface

If you have not heard of Dipity, it is a web app that allows people to create timelines on a browser. Here is an example of a timeline:
http://www.dipity.com/StevePro/Steve-Jobs-Life-and-Career/

How could I implement the timeline functionality that you see in the above link? More specifically, how is the zooming, momentum scrolling, and other UI elements achieved, without Flash?

Under your expertise, what libraries or projects should I be looking at if I want to make a canvas that can zoom in/out, scroll, and go fullscreen like the one you see above?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can view source and see that they're using a lot of jQuery and jQuery plugins:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityAccount.js.v8972.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js.v8078.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipity.js.v9015.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityCookie.js.v8941.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityDialog.js.v8941.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipitySearch.js.v8941.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js.v8078.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/swfupload2.2.0/swfupload.js.v7257.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/swfupload2.2.0/functions.js.v8803.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/carousel.js.v8453.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/typewatch.js.v7961.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js.v8346.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js.v8871.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dipity.com/js/widget.js?key=8307484b5ef1207f7f202fe890a8e14d&sig=5d284fd444ffec2ff3b59dbe2d3d8167"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityForms.js.v8941.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityEvent.js.v8979.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/dipityTopic.js.v8941.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/eventdetail.js.v8490.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/tl_below.js.v6370.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.dipity.com/static/lib/js/ajaxForm.js.v8875.js"></script>
```

You're not going to get any "do A, B, and C and you're done", as they have a *very* complex UI going there. My suggestion would be start on one piece of it (canvas, or mouse wheel events) and just build out a small piece at a time, or find plugins to build the pieces, and then put them all together to build what you're after.

That's the same way pretty much all software is built. You take your individual building blocks, and stack them up to create your own unique creation.